# What's the difference between analyzing a table and rebuilding the index in oracle SQL?

Tags: database, oracle

What's the difference between this and rebuilding the index?

```
ANALYZE TABLE <table_name> COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Comment: One constructs a new index. One analyses it. Constructing an index is expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to discuss here

1) ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS;

Don't use this command.  It is obsolete.  It is designed to collect information on the table to allow queries against it to be run in the best fashion.  Use DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS instead.  And that's just an obvious lead in to that you should have a good read of the Performance Tuning guide to get your head around the optimizer, SQL execution etc

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgdba/index.html

2) Rebuild index

Nothing to do with the table at all.  It is about re-generating the structure that is used for certain queries to efficiently access table data.  It is rare that rebuilds are required.  If you are interested in that, there's a very good whitepaper at

https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/index-internals-rebuilding-the-truth/